# Is there a Java equivalent for Typescript union?

Tags: java, typescript

I wanted to model a few interfaces and classes from a typescript codebase. I wanted to know the best way to model the typescript union in Java.
Something like this-

```
export type a = b | c | d | e | f;
export type b = {
    ..
}
export type c = {
    ..
}
..
```

What would be the best way to model this in Java?

Eg:
`Class A  = Class B or Class C or Class D;`
What this means is that A can be an object of any of these Classes.
I am looking for a solution for classes.
But another example would be.
`export type numberString = string | number`

Comment: If us Java folk knew what that was we might be able help you.  Can you explain what it actually does?  Maybe give an example where you would actually use it?

Comment: @markspace

 ```export type Message = AudioMessage | VideoMessage | ImageMessage;```

So each of these Message/AudioMessage/... are all classes. And Message can be an  object of any of these classes.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no neat equivalent for union types in java. Typically, one will use a common base class of interface (perhaps even a marker interface). Unfortunately this approach does not work if you have types without a common root, which cannot be retrofitted into a new hierarchy.

Comment: Java doesn't have union types, and it doesn't have control-flow type narrowing so union types would not be usable in Java the same way they are usable in Typescript. The proper way to translate this code to Java will depend entirely on what the types actually are and how they're meant to be used.

Comment: Strange enough Java has already `catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)` which manages a union type in the context of the catch clause. Having a similar concept for the return type of a class combined with modern `switch` pattern matching or type-cast with rename like `if (a instanceof MyThing thing)` would be great, but does not seem to exist or being planned.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can use “Union type” since Java 17 (Java 15+, to be more precise). The introduced `sealed` and `permits` keyword can be used to declare “Union types”:

```java
sealed interface Animal permits Dog, Cat {
}

final class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}

final class Cat extends Animal {
    public void meow() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }
}
```

Java can recognize such “Union types”. For example, in Java 21, when you write something like this:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Dog();

        switch (animal) {
            case Dog dog -> {
                dog.bark();
            }
            case Cat cat -> {
                cat.meow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java does not require you to add a redundant `default` to make the switch expression “exhaustive”. But if you remove the `sealed` keyword along with `permits`, you’ll receive an error:

```
An enhanced switch statement should be exhaustive; a default label expected. Java(2099060)
```

Also, when you change `interface Animal` to `class Animal`, you’ll receive the same error, as the switch expression does not take `Animal` itself into account, you have to add another match:

```java
Animal animal = new Dog();

switch (animal) {
    case Dog dog -> {
        dog.bark();
    }
    case Cat cat -> {
        cat.meow();
    }
    case Animal animal1 -> {
        System.out.println("Unknown animal!");
    }
}
```

And that's OK. Java does not report the error anymore.

Answer (score 3):

This does not exists in Java but other JVM-based languages may have such concept (Scala do have traits, so it is not impossible they have union).

You have alternative in Java:

1. Use overloading.
2. Use generics.
3. Use interface (probably the nearest to what you are looking for)

(1) Use overloading: if you need to take a `String` or a `Number`, then create two methods:

```
void foobar(int n) { ... }    
void foobar(String s) { ... }
```

Notice the `int` which is not `Integer` (primitive versus wrapper type)...

(2) Use generics: if you need the object to implements some interface (as a method type parameter):

```
Runnable  run1(Runnable runnable);
<E extends Runnable> E run2(E runnable);
<E extends Runnable & InterfaceA> E run3(E runnable);
```

`run1` and `run2` are mostly the same: if the method return type is `void`, type `E` is probably useless.

The `<E extends Runnable & InterfaceA>` is rarely used, but can restrict `E` so that it implements class/interface `Runnable` and `InterfaceA`.

(3): you may use an interface; Java does not support multiple inheritance, but it does supports default methods and multiple interface:

```
interface B {}
interface A extends B, C, D, E, F {...}
```

The problem is that you can't have an implementation of A extending an implementation of B, C, ..., F. This feature is not present in Java but is called trait in some language.

You may use delegation in such case:

```
class AImpl implements A {
  private final B b;
  public AImpl() {
    this.b = new BImpl();
  }
  public void methodOfB() {b.methodOfB();}
  // and so on
}
```

This won't work for Number and String, or any type for which you can't change the inheritance model (final class, 3rd party classes, etc...).

Comment: *"I am under the impression that union type exists because TypeScript does not supports overloads of method"* This is not at all the sole or main purpose of union types, and union types of functions don't really behave in a similar way to overloads; union types of functions are usually not useful at all because you wouldn't be able to tell the individual function types apart at runtime.

Comment: Probably. I don't do TypeScript. And perhaps one who learned both and understand use cases of union type would be willing to edit my answer rather than downvoting it (the answer is simple: union type does not exists in Java).

Comment: Java does have union types, albeit in a very limited context: `catch(ThisException | ThatException e) {...}` :-) Your provided solutions are the best approximation there are currently.

Comment: Not very sure that Java handle them as such. In any case, there is Java 17 / 21 and other feature that might come close to them: the pattern matching for `switch` would allow to have something similar on the end caller : https://openjdk.org/jeps/441 It is not impossible to have such typing allowing us to indicate that rather than `Object`, some method returns a finite set of types.

Comment: I said nothing: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/UnionType.html